# Using Force-CLI, what do I need to do to get 'force import' to work?

Tags: apex, force-cli

I have a Developer account with Salesforce. A month ago my company asked me to work on an app for Salesforce. At first I only used the Developer Console. Now the project has gotten big, so I would like to use something that might better handle a large number of files. So I went here:

https://force-cli.heroku.com/

And installed the "force" command.

I ran "force export" and got dozens of folders and hundreds of files. This seems great. Then I made a small edit to one of my custom Apex classes. Then I ran:

```
force import -directory=src -c -r -v
```

and I got:

```
Failures - 41
SocialPost-Social Post Layout: Parent entity failed to deploy
Question: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
Reply: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
SocialPost: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
Analytics Cloud Security User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Analytics Cloud Integration User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Admin: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Authenticated Website: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Custom%3A Support Profile: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Custom%3A Sales Profile: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Custom%3A Marketing Profile: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Cross Org Data Proxy User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
ContractManager: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Chatter Moderator User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Chatter Free User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Chatter External User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Customer Community Login User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Customer Community Plus Login User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Customer Community Plus User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
High Volume Customer Portal User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Gold Partner User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
HighVolumePortal: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Force%2Ecom - App Subscription User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
External Identity User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Customer Portal Manager Standard: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Customer Portal Manager Custom: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Customer Community User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Force%2Ecom - Free User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Identity User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Unknown type name 'Folder' specified in package.xml
MarketingProfile: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Partner App Subscription User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Partner Community Login User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Partner Community User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
PlatformPortal: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
ReadOnly: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Silver Partner User: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
SolutionManager: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
Standard: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
StandardAul: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found
```

Why would I get so many errors on default Salesforce workflows and layouts, when I have not made any changes that are relevant to that?

I would expect a simple "force export" followed by a simple "force import" would work without errors.

More crucially, I can't seem to get any changes back to Salesforce. If I do this:

```
force import -directory=src -r -v -u
```

In the verbose output, I see my one file correctly marked as changed:

```
HeddySearchController
    status: unchanged
    id=01p41000008NZbeAAG

HeddySearchResultController
    status: changed
    id=01p41000008NZboAAG

HeddySessionModel
    status: unchanged
    id=01p41000008NZbZAAW
```

But if I now log into the Developer Console, and open that file, I don't see the change.

Is this a permissions issue? What do I need to change so I can use "force import" to get my changes to Salesforce?

Comment: You should try asking on the [github repo](https://github.com/heroku/force/issues). While the project has been [end of life'd](https://github.com/heroku/force/issues/309) the maintainers are still fairly active.

Comment: So how do developers get stuff into Salesforce if they are not using the an IDE? There has to be something more efficient than using the Developer Console?

Comment: Also, the first half of this question, about the errors, is I think a Salesforce question, since "force" is just using the Metadata API.

Comment: [Ant deployment via force migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm), write your own via the [metadata api](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf) (which is something I've done and would recomend to understand the process), something like [Mavensmate](http://mavensmate.com/). You can see some examples in [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146076/how-do-developers-organize-large-apex-visualforce-projects/146078#146078), which you asked, whoops.

Comment: I'd try zipping the files with a package.xml and importing it directly to your sandbox via [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) and test if the files being used by force-cli are valid and import before asking on the github repo. Or, if you don't mind writing a few files, write a few script files to hook into the force migration toolkit and submit your code.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I did manage to get "force import" to work. This was helpful: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2016/09/force-cli-part-4-deploying-metadata.html  , but he neglects to say that I need to copy over the "-meta.xml" files in the "classes" directory, as well as the ".cls" files.