# Best IDE for Lightning Development?

Tags: lightning, eclipse, lightning-development

I am currently using Eclipse Ide for Force.com for development. But i don't think it is best setup for Lightning? Can anyone suggest What is Best Combinataion of Editor , Ide for Lightning development?

Comment: This is a very subjective question that's a matter of opinion. What other IDE's have you tried? There's a plug-in solution for Sublime Text. Beyond that, there isn't any other option other than the Developer Console that I'm aware of. Important to consider is that at present, Eclipse IDE will always have the latest/fastest updates from Salesforce.

Comment: @crmprogdev Almost all IDEs I know and use have Lightning support to some degree, actually.

Comment: @sfdcfox Must be that they're rapidly increasingly then. Wasn't long ago that Sublime Text was the only option. Regardless, it's still a personal preference kind of thing and also a matter of what you're willing to pay for.

Comment: @crmprogdev Perhaps this question could be salvaged as a community wiki of known IDEs with pros and cons?

Comment: @sfdcfox I think that would have merit if it were along the lines of what features each IDE supported, whether paid vs free, etc; the focusing being on attempting to avoid excessive subjectivity. We'd want to avoid answers with "I like this one's cool interface", preferring instead: "It has feature A which I find useful for..."

Comment: This has a good list: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146076/how-do-developers-organize-large-apex-visualforce-projects/146078#146078 - Personally I use IC with intelliJ and dumped MM when it stoped working with TLS disablement. The new version of MM is cumbersome and buggy IMHO. Each IDE implements lightning in different ways. IC has good support but organization of files is limited by IntelliJ, Eclipse organizes better but is a resource hog and less features than IntelliJ. Everything is a trade off and based on your preference

Comment: I think JetForcer is the best IDE for Lightning developers, its features rock https://jetforcer.com/features#lightning

Answer (score 6):

There is no "best" editor, as each has different features that may be attractive to a particular developer. For example, one might want an IDE that also has Java support, or also has Git support, or has a particular OS requirement, or is cloud-based, etc. Instead, we present a collection of known IDEs that support Lightning, and you can decide for yourself which is the best for your personal needs.

Some features that will be mentioned are as follows:

## Cost

- Free: The IDE has no upfront cost for full functionality
- Paid: The IDE requires an upfront cost to enable full functionality
- Subscription: The IDE requires an ongoing cost to enable full functionality

## Auto-Complete

- Limited Auto-Complete: The IDE can suggest code snippets, but they may not always make sense
- Full Auto-Complete: The IDE can suggest code snippets that are context sensitive

## Phantom Files

- Phantom Files: The IDE auto-suggests files that could be part of the bundle

## Software Type

- Windows: Only operates under Windows systems
- Linux: Only operates under Linux systems
- Mac: Only operates under Mac systems
- Chrome: Only operates in the Chrome browser
- Cross-Platform: Runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac
- Cloud: Runs on any modern browser

## Software Status

- Alpha: Is generally unusable or unavailable to the public
- Beta: There are some known limitations, but is still generally useful

---

[Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) is developed by salesforce.com, and is based on Eclipse, so you can install additional software to support using Git or SVN, or additional languages you might need to develop in. One notable limitation is that the IDE tends to block itself (and you) from doing too much at once when syncing with the server. *Features: Free, Cross-Platform*

**Force.com IDE 2** is the next generation IDE being built by salesforce.com, which leverages the new DX toolkit. Currently only available to those in the pilot, it is also built on Eclipse, but includes better support for repository-based development and Lightning. It is expected to be out at some point this year, depending on the success of the pilot. *Features: Free, Alpha, Cross-Platform*

[Cloud9](https://c9.io/) is a cloud-based IDE that spins up Ubuntu Virtual Machines, so you not only get a full IDE, but you can also open up a terminal with access to dozens of Linux built-in commands, useful if you're familiar with Linux. *Features: Subscription, Limited Auto-Complete, Phantom Files, Beta, Cloud*

[Developer Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Console) is the built-in IDE for salesforce.com. Notably, it is the only active IDE that appears to support Check Points, a feature that lets you dump the entire heap when a line of code is reached. *Features: Free, Phantom Files, Cloud*

[MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) is a plug-in that is supported by [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) (paid editor) and [Atom](https://atom.io/) (free editor). Note that this IDE is unique in the sense that it requires two separate software installs instead of just one install plus a plugin. *Features: Free, Limited Auto-Complete, Cross-Platform*

[Illuminated Cloud](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7831-illuminated-cloud) is a JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA. It has most of the features that other IDEs do, but the auto-completion is notably better than most. *Features: Paid, Cross-Platform, Full Auto-Complete*. Also includes an offline debugger where you can step through the logs in context with your code and checkpoints like a traditional debugger.

[Metaforce](http://metaforce.org/) is an IDE that is actually an IDE built to run as a Chrome extension, Windows HTML app, or Mac HTML app. It has a different UI that some people might prefer. *Features: Free, Windows, Mac, Chrome, Partial Auto-Complete*

[Welkins Suite](https://welkinsuite.com)..details needed..

---

*This is a **COMMUNITY WIKI**. Please help by contributing corrections and updates.*

Comment: Illuminated Cloud is not free: http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/purchase

Comment: @CharlesT Thanks, I thought it was. I've edited that in.